# Hidden Validator Controls Still Validate?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I've set up a page that uses JavaScript to hide or show rows in an HTML table, depending on the state of a checkbox.

So far, so good. But this is a data entry form and some rows include validation controls. However, it appears that if I hide a row (using JavaScript: `style.display = 'none'`) that contains a validation control, the control still validates on an attempt to postback.

Can anyone suggest a way I can do this but have the validation controls not do anything if that row is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the validator, using this technique of disabling it using the ValidatorEnable method: http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/08/11/87708.aspx

Comment: That's a new one for me. Thanks.